# How to enable/disable the row double click editing property of radgrid based on condition

Tags: asp.net, gridview, radgrid, telerik-grid

I have the following code

Javascript

```
function RowDblClick(sender, eventArgs)
                             {
                                window.radopen("SourceFileAdmin.aspx?SourceSystemFileId=" + eventArgs.getDataKeyValue("SourceSystemFileId"), "UserListDialog");
                            }
```

Aspx Grid Code

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
                        GridLines="None" ShowGroupPanel="True" Skin="Black" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        Width="100%" AllowAutomaticInserts="false" AllowAutomaticUpdates="false" PagerStyle-Mode="NumericPages"
                        OnItemInserted="GridItemInserted"
                        onitemdatabound="GridItemDataBound">
.............................................
........................................
..................................................
                            <ClientSettings>
                            <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
                            <ClientEvents OnRowDblClick="RowDblClick" />
                        </ClientSettings>
</telerik:RadGrid>
<asp:Button ID="AddSrcButton" runat="server" Text="Add New" OnClientClick="return ShowInsertForm();" />
```

My actual question is to disable or enable RowDblClick property based on the user permission
This is my sample code in the aspx.cs file where i want to set the edit or view permission for radgrid

```
this.AddSrcButton.Enabled = this.Privilige.CanModify;//the value will be true or false
 this.RadGrid.Enabled=this.Privilige.CanModify;
```

//the value will be true or false ,based on this value i want to enable/disable my rowdblclick,can any one help out to figure out where i am doinfg wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can set the row double click on the server side programatically

```
if(!this.Privilige.CanModify)
    RadGrid.ClientSettings.ClientEvents.OnRowDblClick = "";
```

Beware though to renable the page you will probably need to refresh it all to get the clientside javascript to be loaded again, unless you move that into the .cs file